# How to redirect opera users?

Tags: html

Unlike the IE code :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "link"
//-->
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

is this not working

```
<!--[if opera]>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "link2"
//-->
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

What is the correct way of doing this ?

i got it the code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.opera) {
   <!--
window.location = "link.php"
//-->
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no correct way to discriminate based on browser choice.

Comment: Why would you want to redirect Opera users? What problem does that solve?

Answer (score 1):

`<!--[if IE]>` is not a HTML known tag or statement, and it's just understandable by *IE*. (Really this provided by Microsoft to IE). You can use **JavaScript** to achieve your purpose:

```
var isOpera = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") > -1;
if(isOpera) {
    window.location = "link"
}
```